# Why do desktops depend on folders?

Tags: desktop

I think, it'd make a lot more sense to have desktops be identified by names (like bookmarks). If it's deemed desirable that they can be stored in different locations, it'd make sense to select what file shall be used to store the desktop. So why does one have to select a directory instead (with the file name always being the same)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the question, and I agree with its suggestion.

I don't think there is *any* good reason why `desktop.el` accepts only a *directory* (folder) argument and not, alternatively or additionally, a *file* argument for `desktop-read`.

After all, that function is about reading a desktop **file**.  Why make it impossible to pass a file to the function?  Why make the function *only* get the file to read from a directory or set of directories?

In effect, the design is that you can have only one desktop file per directory. Why? No reason, as far as I can see.

I think it was just a design oversight, based on a limited view of what desktops can be or how users could use them. One particular use case was hard-coded in such a way that it is impossible, using only the vanilla `desktop.el` code, to work with multiple desktop files in the same directory.

In [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) I had a need to let users bookmark multiple desktops and be able to put the desktop files in arbitrary folders anywhere - including multiple files in the same directory.  So I defined function `bmkp-desktop-read` as a replacement (for the Bookmark+ code) for `desktop-read`.

What `desktop.el` should have done (should do) is to define `desktop-read` to read a desktop file (argument `FILE`). And *on top of that* it could easily *also* have code that lets you have a path of directories (option `desktop-path`), which is used as today, expecting (as a convenience for one use case) a single desktop file in those directories.

---

Above is my answer to "*why*" it is the way it is.  You can get the feature you're apparently looking for, which is multiple desktop files per folder, by using Bookmark+. You can have any number of desktop bookmarks, and their desktop files can be anywhere. You need not even care where their files are.

To change to a given desktop, just "jump" to its bookmark, as you would jump to any bookmark. You can use key **`C-x j K`** to complete against only desktop bookmarks, i.e., to have only desktop bookmarks to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a directory was used primarily because more than one file is saved there.

As well as the desktop file itself (`desktop-base-file-name`) there is also a lock file (`desktop-base-lock-name`).

Those are just variables, so there's nothing stopping you from writing a custom command to read a `desktop-base-file-name` from the user, derive an appropriate `desktop-base-lock-name`, and load that desktop file instead of the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can config `desktop.el` in order to assign desktop with names. Here is a code adapted from [this post](http://scottfrazersblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/emacs-named-desktop-sessions.html):

```el
(use-package desktop
  :config
  (defvar my-desktop-session-dir "PATH*"
    "Directory to save desktop sessions in")

  (defvar my-desktop-session-name-hist nil
    "Desktop session name history")

  (defun mda/desktop-save (&optional name)
    "Save desktop by name."
    (interactive)
    (unless name
      (setq name (my-desktop-get-session-name "Save session" t)))
    (when name
      (make-directory (concat my-desktop-session-dir name) t)
      (desktop-save (concat my-desktop-session-dir name) t)))

  (defun mda/desktop-read (&optional name)
    "Read desktop by name."
    (interactive)
    (unless name
      (setq name (my-desktop-get-session-name "Load session")))
    (when name
      (desktop-clear)
      (desktop-read (concat my-desktop-session-dir name))))

  (defun mda/desktop-save-and-clear ()
    "Save and clear desktop."
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively 'mda/desktop-save)
    (desktop-clear)
    (setq desktop-dirname nil))

  (defun my-desktop-get-current-name ()
    "Get the current desktop name."
    (when desktop-dirname
      (let ((dirname (substring desktop-dirname 0 -1)))
        (when (string= (file-name-directory dirname) my-desktop-session-dir)
          (file-name-nondirectory dirname)))))

  (defun my-desktop-get-session-name (prompt &optional use-default)
    "Get a session name."
    (let* ((default (and use-default (my-desktop-get-current-name)))
           (full-prompt (concat prompt (if default
                                           (concat " (default " default "): ")
                                         ": "))))
      (completing-read full-prompt (and (file-exists-p my-desktop-session-dir)
                                        (directory-files my-desktop-session-dir))
                       nil nil nil my-desktop-session-name-hist default)))

  (defun my-desktop-kill-emacs-hook ()
    "Save desktop before killing emacs."
    (when (file-exists-p (concat my-desktop-session-dir "last-session"))
      (setq desktop-file-modtime
            (nth 5 (file-attributes (desktop-full-file-name (concat my-desktop-session-dir "last-session"))))))
    (mda/desktop-save "last-session"))

  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'my-desktop-kill-emacs-hook)
  :bind 
  ("C-c s c" . mda/desktop-save-and-clear) ;;Save and clear desktop
  ("C-c s s" . mda/desktop-save)  ;;Save current session by name
  ("C-c s r" . mda/desktop-read)  ;;Load a session by name
  )
```

*Replace PATH by the path to the folder where you want your sessions to be stored.